# PCA on X to capture the most variance of Y

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

PCA maximises the variation in $X$. Now, suppose $X$ is causal to $Y$. Is there then any analogous way to decompose $X$ into the principal components that cause the most variation in $Y$.

For an example, suppose linear combinations of the first 2 features $x_1$ and $x_2$ from $X$ can predict all of $Y$. Would it be possible to dimension reduce $X$ to these only?

(Apologies in advance for the somewhat unclearly posed question. Any edits in the right direction highly appreciated!)

Comment: What is the collection of variables? Just $\{ X, Y \}$?

Comment: Yeah, just $(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$ and $(y_1, ... , y_m)$. I used $X$ and $Y$ to denote the standard $p \times n$ and $p \times m$ matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation